# Question on Drupal and HTTP requests

Tags: 6, http-request

I am using the [`drupal_http_request`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7) method and It seems to work well. When I use it, I send by POST from site A, a return URL (which would be site C) to site B that I am directing drupal to go to. So site A goes to B, but returns to A at this point.

I noticed that if I give the die command (on site A) right after I use [`drupal_http_request`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7) my browser opens to site C instead of going right back to A. Would this happen even if site C was on the same domain as site A? Obviously this would not be the same exact location of A.

e.g. A = www.example.com/test and C = www.example.com/test2

Comment: It might help to post a code snippet of what you're doing. It's not very clear what you're doing and how it relates to where you're redirecting.